# Dynamic URL update in deployed web app

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, servlets, web-applications

> What I have ?

Two web applications which inter-communicates using sendRedirect

> What I want ?

To deploy those web apps on AWS

> Problems

1)  When I am deploying one web application to AWS , I dont have url of second web application because it is not deployed yet.  I must need to specify url of second web app so first web app can communicate with second web app. 
2) I can not deploy second web app initially because it also redirects to first web app (inter-communication ) i.e. If i deploy second web app initially problem continues because I don't have url of first web application

> Straight Solution

1) Deploy first web app with dummy url of second web app. (Here I wll get actual url of first web app)
2) Deploy second web app with actual url of first web app (Here I will get actual url of second web app)
3) Update first web app with actual url of second web app and redeploy the first web app

Above solution is time consuming and needs rework.

> Is there any efficient way  by which I can dynamically update the url
>   used in web app , and no need to redeploy app

Comment: Have you considered allocating a static url with AWS Route53 and then directing any webapp deployed to that url? There are a number of ways this could be achieved with AWS, we use an Elastic Load Balancer for that purpose but I can think of a number of other solutions.

Comment: @YaronIdan I think its nice approach to use static url . Please mention other solutions also.

Comment: Well, all solutions would include Route53 to assign a static URL, then you the rest of the job is assigning the new server's into that url. In order to choose the best course of action I need to know more about your deployment process. How are you deploying your web app? Do you have some kind of configuration management tool or are you doing it manually?

Comment: @YaronIdan I am using Elastic BeanStalk for deployment. I am more curious about "is AWS provide any way to configure properties of webapp  from outside?" For example , to connect RDS instance we can set URL of RDS in web app dynamically

Comment: Almost every manual process could be turned into a piece of code and be used for dynamic configuration. If you are using Elastic BeanStalk for deploying, then you app is already given a static URL as part of the deploy process (usually <appname>.elsticbeanstalk.com), you can use this url to communicate between these two apps. Connecting the RDS instance is a different matter, and will require a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the knitty gritty details on how it can/should be implemented exactly but I would look for a kind of publish/subscribe mechanism in which both Web servers are initially booted and listening for each other. The web server remains pending until it receives a notification the other is ready to receive messages. When one of the web servers is ready to receive messages it will publish a notification. Once the other web server is ready it will receive the notification (containing the URL at which it can be received) and publish also a notification that it is ready to receive messages.

Another possibility would be create load ballancers for both web servers at a fixed address. When the web server is started it will be added to the load ballancer hiding where the server exactly is deployed.

Hope this makes sense to you.